# Find the directory part (minus the filename) of a full path in access 97

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-access-97

For various reasons, I'm stuck in Access 97 and need to get only the path part of a full pathname.

For example, the name

```
c:\whatever dir\another dir\stuff.mdb
```

should become

```
c:\whatever dir\another dir\
```

This site has some suggestions on how to do it:
http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/parse_path_filename.html

But they seem rather hideous.  There must be a better way, right?

Comment: What's hideous about it? It looks like pretty simple code to me, and I had my own versions written for A97 that are still running in apps today, even though they provide better builtin functions than were available in A97.

Comment: Removed from questions: Is CurrentProject.Path available in Access 97?

Comment: Response: No, CurrentProject is entirely missing from Access 97. There's CurrentDb.Name, however, but that's the full path including filename. – apenwarr

Comment: With the progress of time, the accepted answer is extremely outdated.  Perhaps another answer should be chosen?

Answer (score 73):

You can do something simple like: `Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\"))`

Example:

```
Function GetDirectory(path)
   GetDirectory = Left(path, InStrRev(path, Application.PathSeparator))
End Function
```

Comment: Champion!! Best solution by far!

Comment: just add the variable declarations correctly (as string)

Answer (score 22):

I always used the `FileSystemObject` for this sort of thing. Here's a little wrapper function I used. Be sure to reference the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

```
Function StripFilename(sPathFile As String) As String

'given a full path and file, strip the filename off the end and return the path

Dim filesystem As New FileSystemObject

StripFilename = filesystem.GetParentFolderName(sPathFile) & "\"

Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Bad idea, because it requires a reference to work. If you insist on it, you should use late binding.

Comment: Since when are references a bad idea? Access itself requires references to work. 0_o

Comment: This works great in vba. Only thing i had to do was make filesystem a regular object and then set it to the full type of FileSystemObject

Answer (score 13):

This seems to work.  The above doesn't in Excel 2010.

```
Function StripFilename(sPathFile As String) As String
'given a full path and file, strip the filename off the end and return the path
Dim filesystem As Object

Set filesystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

StripFilename = filesystem.GetParentFolderName(sPathFile) & "\"

Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: References can also be set In Excel VBA. In the VBA editor, click the Tools menu and then References. Tick the box in the list next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime." The FileSystemObject type should then be available to declare in the Dim statement.

Comment: This is basically the same function posted by @Siddharth Rout but it works without a reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just needing the path of the MDB currently open in the Access UI, I'd suggest writing a function that parses CurrentDB.Name and then stores the result in a Static variable inside the function. Something like this:

```
Public Function CurrentPath() As String
  Dim strCurrentDBName As String
  Static strPath As String
  Dim i As Integer

  If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
     strCurrentDBName = CurrentDb.Name
     For i = Len(strCurrentDBName) To 1 Step -1
       If Mid(strCurrentDBName, i, 1) = "\" Then
          strPath = Left(strCurrentDBName, i)
          Exit For
       End If
    Next
  End If
  CurrentPath = strPath
End Function
```

This has the advantage that it only loops through the name one time.

Of course, it only works with the file that's open in the user interface.

Another way to write this would be to use the functions provided at the [link](http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/parse_path_filename.html) inside the function above, thus:

```
Public Function CurrentPath() As String
  Static strPath As String

  If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
     strPath = FolderFromPath(CurrentDB.Name)
  End If
  CurrentPath = strPath
End Function
```

This makes retrieving the current path very efficient while utilizing code that can be used for finding the path for any filename/path.

Answer (score 2):

vFilename="C:\Informes\Indicadores\Program\Ind_Cont_PRv.txt"

vDirFile = Replace(vFilename, Dir(vFileName, vbDirectory), "")

' Result=C:\Informes\Indicadores_Contraloria\Programa\Versiones anteriores\

Comment: For my purposes, this is the most useful answer. Brevity, no objects, simple, lightweight!

Comment: Good one, but it only works if the file exists.

Answer (score 1):

left(currentdb.Name,instr(1,currentdb.Name,dir(currentdb.Name))-1)

The Dir function will return only the file portion of the full path.  Currentdb.Name is used here, but it could be any full path string.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like it wouldn't work if the filename part appears as part of the path, eg. "c:\whatever.txt\x\y\z\whatever.txt" would be split incorrectly.

Comment: Correct.  I'll edit my answer as soon as that happens to me or anyone I know.  So far it hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident in your input parameters, you can use this single line of code which uses the native Split and Join functions and Excel native Application.pathSeparator.

```
Split(Join(Split(strPath, "."), Application.pathSeparator), Application.pathSeparator)
```

If you want a more *extensive* function, the code below is tested in Windows and should also work on Mac (though not tested).  Be sure to also copy the supporting function GetPathSeparator, or modify the code to use Application.pathSeparator.  Note, this is a first draft; I should really refactor it to be more concise.

```
Private Sub ParsePath2Test()
    'ParsePath2(DrivePathFileExt, -2) returns a multi-line string for debugging.
    Dim p As String, n As Integer

    Debug.Print String(2, vbCrLf)

    If True Then
        Debug.Print String(2, vbCrLf)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows\notepad.exe", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows\SysWOW64", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AcLayers.dll", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\.fakedir", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", -2)
    End If

    If True Then
        Debug.Print String(1, vbCrLf)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows\notepad.exe", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows\SysWOW64", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows\SysWOW64\", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows\SysWOW64\AcLayers.dll", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows\SysWOW64\.fakedir", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("\Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", -2)
    End If

    If True Then
        Debug.Print String(1, vbCrLf)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows\notepad.exe", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\AcLayers.dll", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\.fakedir", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2(".fakedir", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("fakefile.txt", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("fakefile.onenote", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("C:\Personal\Workspace\Code\PythonVenvs\xlwings_test\.idea", -2)
        Debug.Print ParsePath2("Windows", -2)   ' Expected to raise error 52
    End If

    If True Then
        Debug.Print String(2, vbCrLf)
        Debug.Print "ParsePath2 ""\Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext"" with different ReturnType values"
        Debug.Print , "{empty}", "D", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext")(1)
        Debug.Print , "0", "D", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 0)(1)
        Debug.Print , "1", "ext", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 1)
        Debug.Print , "10", "file", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 10)
        Debug.Print , "11", "file.ext", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 11)
        Debug.Print , "100", "path", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 100)
        Debug.Print , "110", "path\file", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 110)
        Debug.Print , "111", "path\file.ext", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 111)
        Debug.Print , "1000", "D", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 1000)
        Debug.Print , "1100", "D:\path", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 1100)
        Debug.Print , "1110", "D:\p\file", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 1110)
        Debug.Print , "1111", "D:\p\f.ext", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 1111)
        On Error GoTo EH:
        ' This is expected to presetn an error:
        p = "Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext"
        n = 1010
        Debug.Print "1010", "D:\p\file.ext", ParsePath2("Windows\SysWOW64\fakefile.ext", 1010)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Exit Sub
EH:
    Debug.Print , CStr(n), "Error: "; Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function ParsePath2(ByVal DrivePathFileExt As String _
                         , Optional ReturnType As Integer = 0)
' Writen by Chris Advena.  You may modify and use this code provided you leave
' this credit in the code.
' Parses the input DrivePathFileExt string into individual components (drive
' letter, folders, filename and extension) and returns the portions you wish
' based on ReturnType.
' Returns either an array of strings (ReturnType = 0) or an individual string
' (all other defined ReturnType values).
'
' Parameters:
'   DrivePathFileExt: The full drive letter, path, filename and extension
'   ReturnType: -2 or a string up of to 4 ones with leading or lagging zeros
'              (e.g., 0001)
'      -2: special code for debugging use in ParsePath2Test().
'          Results in printing verbose information to the Immediate window.
'       0: default: Array(driveStr, pathStr, fileStr, extStr)
'       1: extension
'      10: filename stripped of extension
'      11: filename.extension, excluding drive and folders
'     100: folders, excluding drive letter filename and extension
'     111: folders\filename.extension, excluding drive letter
'    1000: drive leter only
'    1100: drive:\folders,  excluding filename and extension
'    1110: drive:\folders\filename, excluding extension
'    1010, 0101, 1001: invalid ReturnTypes.  Will result raise error 380, Value
'          is not valid.

    Dim driveStr As String, pathStr As String
    Dim fileStr As String, extStr As String
    Dim drivePathStr As String
    Dim pathFileExtStr As String, fileExtStr As String
    Dim s As String, cnt As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, slashStr As String
    Dim dotLoc As Integer, slashLoc As Integer, colonLoc As Integer
    Dim extLen As Integer, fileLen As Integer, pathLen As Integer
    Dim errStr As String

    DrivePathFileExt = Trim(DrivePathFileExt)

    If DrivePathFileExt = "" Then
        fileStr = ""
        extStr = ""
        fileExtStr = ""
        pathStr = ""
        pathFileExtStr = ""
        drivePathStr = ""
        GoTo ReturnResults
    End If

    ' Determine if Dos(/) or UNIX(\) slash is used
    slashStr = GetPathSeparator(DrivePathFileExt)

' Find location of colon, rightmost slash and dot.
    ' COLON: colonLoc and driveStr
    colonLoc = 0
    driveStr = ""
    If Mid(DrivePathFileExt, 2, 1) = ":" Then
        colonLoc = 2
        driveStr = Left(DrivePathFileExt, 1)
    End If
    #If Mac Then
        pathFileExtStr = DrivePathFileExt
    #Else ' Windows
        pathFileExtStr = ""
        If Len(DrivePathFileExt) > colonLoc _
        Then pathFileExtStr = Mid(DrivePathFileExt, colonLoc + 1)
    #End If

    ' SLASH: slashLoc, fileExtStr and fileStr
    ' Find the rightmost path separator (Win backslash or Mac Fwdslash).
    slashLoc = InStrRev(DrivePathFileExt, slashStr, -1, vbBinaryCompare)

    ' DOT: dotLoc and extStr
    ' Find rightmost dot.  If that dot is not part of a relative reference,
    ' then set dotLoc.  dotLoc is meant to apply to the dot before an extension,
    ' NOT relative path reference dots.  REl ref dots appear as "." or ".." at
    ' the very leftmost of the path string.
    dotLoc = InStrRev(DrivePathFileExt, ".", -1, vbTextCompare)
    If Left(DrivePathFileExt, 1) = "." And dotLoc <= 2 Then dotLoc = 0
    If slashLoc + 1 = dotLoc Then
        dotLoc = 0
        If Len(extStr) = 0 And Right(pathFileExtStr, 1) <> slashStr _
        Then pathFileExtStr = pathFileExtStr & slashStr
    End If
    #If Not Mac Then
        ' In windows, filenames cannot end with a dot (".").
        If dotLoc = Len(DrivePathFileExt) Then
            s = "Error in FileManagementMod.ParsePath2 function.  " _
                & "DrivePathFileExt " & DrivePathFileExt _
                & " cannot end iwth a dot ('.')."
            Err.Raise 52, "FileManagementMod.ParsePath2", s
        End If
    #End If

    ' extStr
    extStr = ""
    If dotLoc > 0 And (dotLoc < Len(DrivePathFileExt)) _
    Then extStr = Mid(DrivePathFileExt, dotLoc + 1)

    ' fileExtStr
    fileExtStr = ""
    If slashLoc > 0 _
    And slashLoc < Len(DrivePathFileExt) _
    And dotLoc > slashLoc Then
        fileExtStr = Mid(DrivePathFileExt, slashLoc + 1)
    End If


' Validate the input: DrivePathFileExt
    s = ""
    #If Mac Then
        If InStr(1, DrivePathFileExt, ":") > 0 Then
            s = "DrivePathFileExt ('" & DrivePathFileExt _
                & "')has invalid format.  " _
                & "UNIX/Mac filenames cannot contain a colon ('.')."
        End If
    #End If
    If Not colonLoc = 0 And slashLoc = 0 And dotLoc = 0 _
    And Left(DrivePathFileExt, 1) <> slashStr _
    And Left(DrivePathFileExt, 1) <> "." Then
        s = "DrivePathFileExt ('" & DrivePathFileExt _
            & "') has invalid format.  " _
            & "Good example: 'C:\folder\file.txt'"
    ElseIf colonLoc <> 0 And colonLoc <> 2 Then
        ' We are on Windows and there is a colon; it can only be
        ' in position 2.
        s = "DrivePathFileExt ('" & DrivePathFileExt _
            & "') has invalid format.  " _
            & "In the  Windows operating system, " _
            & "a colon (':') can only be the second character '" _
            & "of a valid file path. "
    ElseIf Left(DrivePathFileExt, 1) = ":" _
    Or InStr(3, DrivePathFileExt, ":", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'If path contains a drive letter, it must contain at least one slash.
        s = "DrivePathFileExt ('" & DrivePathFileExt _
            & "') has invalid format.  " _
            & "Colon can only appear in the second character position." _
            & slashStr & "')."
    ElseIf colonLoc > 0 And slashLoc = 0 _
    And Len(DrivePathFileExt) > 2 Then
        'If path contains a drive letter, it must contain at least one slash.
        s = "DrivePathFileExt ('" & DrivePathFileExt _
            & "') has invalid format.  " _
            & "The last dot ('.') cannot be before the last file separator '" _
            & slashStr & "')."
    ElseIf colonLoc = 2 _
    And InStr(1, DrivePathFileExt, slashStr, vbTextCompare) = 0 _
    And Len(DrivePathFileExt) > 2 Then
        ' There is a colon, but no file separator (slash).  This is invalid.
        s = "DrivePathFileExt ('" & DrivePathFileExt _
            & "') has invalid format.  " _
            & "If a drive letter is included, then there must be at " _
            & "least one file separator character ('" & slashStr & "')."
    ElseIf Len(driveStr) > 0 And Len(DrivePathFileExt) > 2 And slashLoc = 0 Then
        ' If path contains a drive letter and is more than 2 character long
        ' (e.g., 'C:'), it must contain at least one slash.
        s = "DrivePathFileExt cannot contain a drive letter but no path separator."
    End If
    If Len(s) > 0 Then
    End If



' Determine if DrivePathFileExt = DrivePath
' or  = Path (with no fileStr or extStr components).
    If Right(DrivePathFileExt, 1) = slashStr _
    Or slashLoc = 0 _
    Or dotLoc = 0 _
    Or (dotLoc > 0 And dotLoc <= slashLoc + 1) Then
        ' If rightmost character is the slashStr, then no fileExt exists, just drivePath
        ' If no dot found, then no extension.  Assume a folder is after the last slashstr,
        ' not a filename.
        ' If a dot is found (extension exists),
        ' If a rightmost dot appears one-char to the right of the rightmost slash
        '    or anywhere before (left) of that, it is not a file/ext separator. Exmaple:
        '    'C:\folder1\.folder2' Then
        ' If no slashes, then no fileExt exists.  It must just be a driveletter.
        ' DrivePathFileExt contains no file or ext name.
        fileStr = ""
        extStr = ""
        fileExtStr = ""
        pathStr = pathFileExtStr
        drivePathStr = DrivePathFileExt
        GoTo ReturnResults
    Else
        ' fileStr
        fileStr = ""
        If slashLoc > 0 Then
            If Len(extStr) = 0 Then
                fileStr = fileExtStr
            Else
                ' length of filename excluding dot and extension.
                i = Len(fileExtStr) - Len(extStr) - 1
                fileStr = Left(fileExtStr, i)
            End If
        Else
                s = "Error in FileManagementMod.ParsePath2 function. " _
                    & "*** Unhandled scenario: find fileStr when slashLoc = 0. *** "
                Err.Raise 52, "FileManagementMod.ParsePath2", s
        End If

        ' pathStr
        pathStr = ""
        ' length of pathFileExtStr excluding fileExt.
        i = Len(pathFileExtStr) - Len(fileExtStr)
        pathStr = Left(pathFileExtStr, i)

        ' drivePathStr
        drivePathStr = ""
        ' length of DrivePathFileExt excluding dot and extension.
        i = Len(DrivePathFileExt) - Len(fileExtStr)
        drivePathStr = Left(DrivePathFileExt, i)
    End If

ReturnResults:
    ' ReturnType uses a 4-digit binary code: dpfe = drive path file extension,
    ' where 1 = return in array and 0 = do not return in array
    ' -2, and 0 are special cases that do not follow the code.

    ' Note: pathstr is determined with the tailing slashstr
    If Len(drivePathStr) > 0 And Right(drivePathStr, 1) <> slashStr _
    Then drivePathStr = drivePathStr & slashStr
    If Len(pathStr) > 0 And Right(pathStr, 1) <> slashStr _
    Then pathStr = pathStr & slashStr
    #If Not Mac Then
        ' Including this code add a slash to the beginnning where missing.
        ' the downside is that it would create an absolute path where a
        ' sub-path of the current folder is intended.
        'If colonLoc = 0 Then
        '    If Len(drivePathStr) > 0 And Not IsIn(Left(drivePathStr, 1), slashStr, ".") _
             Then drivePathStr = slashStr & drivePathStr
        '    If Len(pathStr) > 0 And Not IsIn(Left(pathStr, 1), slashStr, ".") _
             Then pathStr = slashStr & pathStr
        '    If Len(pathFileExtStr) > 0 And Not IsIn(Left(pathFileExtStr, 1), slashStr, ".") _
             Then pathFileExtStr = slashStr & pathFileExtStr
        'End If
    #End If
    Select Case ReturnType
        Case -2  ' used for ParsePath2Test() only.
            ParsePath2 = "DrivePathFileExt          " _
                        & CStr(Nz(DrivePathFileExt, "{empty string}")) _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " _
                        & "--------------    -----------------------------------------" _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "D:\Path\          " & drivePathStr _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "\path[\file.ext]  " & pathFileExtStr _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "\path\            " & pathStr _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "file.ext          " & fileExtStr _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "file              " & fileStr _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "ext               " & extStr _
                        & vbCrLf & "        " & "D                 " & driveStr _
                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            ' My custom debug printer prints to Immediate winodw and log file.
            ' Dbg.Prnt 2, ParsePath2
            Debug.Print ParsePath2
        Case 1      '0001: ext
            ParsePath2 = extStr
        Case 10     '0010: file
            ParsePath2 = fileStr
        Case 11     '0011: file.ext
            ParsePath2 = fileExtStr
        Case 100    '0100: path
            ParsePath2 = pathStr
        Case 110    '0110: (path, file)
            ParsePath2 = pathStr & fileStr
        Case 111    '0111:
            ParsePath2 = pathFileExtStr
        Case 1000
            ParsePath2 = driveStr
        Case 1100
            ParsePath2 = drivePathStr
        Case 1110
            ParsePath2 = drivePathStr & fileStr
        Case 1111
            ParsePath2 = DrivePathFileExt
        Case 1010, 101, 1001
            s = "Error in FileManagementMod.ParsePath2 function.  " _
                & "Value of Paramter (ReturnType = " _
                & CStr(ReturnType) & ") is not valid."
            Err.Raise 380, "FileManagementMod.ParsePath2", s
        Case Else   '   default: 0
            ParsePath2 = Array(driveStr, pathStr, fileStr, extStr)
    End Select

End Function
```

Supporting function GetPathSeparatorTest extends the native Application.pathSeparator (or bypasses when needed) to work on Mac and Win.  It can also takes an optional path string and will try to determine the path separator used in the string (favoring the OS native path separator).

```
Private Sub GetPathSeparatorTest()
    Dim s As String
    Debug.Print "GetPathSeparator(s):"
    Debug.Print "s not provided: ", GetPathSeparator
    s = "C:\folder1\folder2\file.ext"
    Debug.Print "s = "; s, GetPathSeparator(DrivePathFileExt:=s)
    s = "C:/folder1/folder2/file.ext"
    Debug.Print "s = "; s, GetPathSeparator(DrivePathFileExt:=s)
End Sub
Function GetPathSeparator(Optional DrivePathFileExt As String = "") As String
' by Chris Advena
' Finds the path separator from a string, DrivePathFileExt.
' If DrivePathFileExt is not provided, return the operating system path separator
' (Windows = backslash, Mac = forwardslash).
' Mac/Win compatible.

    ' Initialize
    Dim retStr As String: retStr = ""
    Dim OSSlash As String: OSSlash = ""
    Dim OSOppositeSlash As String: OSOppositeSlash = ""
        Dim PathFileExtSlash As String

    GetPathSeparator = ""
    retStr = ""

    ' Determine if OS expects fwd or back slash ("/" or "\").
    On Error GoTo EH
    OSSlash = Application.pathSeparator

    If DrivePathFileExt = "" Then
    ' Input parameter DrivePathFileExt is empty, so use OS file separator.
        retStr = OSSlash
    Else
    ' Input parameter DrivePathFileExt provided.  See if it contains / or \.
        ' Set OSOppositeSlash to the opposite slash the OS expects.
        OSOppositeSlash = "\"
        If OSSlash = "\" Then OSOppositeSlash = "/"

        ' If DrivePathFileExt does NOT contain OSSlash
        ' and DOES contain OSOppositeSlash, return OSOppositeSlash.
        ' Otherwise, assume OSSlash is correct.
        retStr = OSSlash
        If InStr(1, DrivePathFileExt, OSSlash, vbTextCompare) = 0 _
        And InStr(1, DrivePathFileExt, OSOppositeSlash, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            retStr = OSOppositeSlash
        End If
    End If

    GetPathSeparator = retStr
Exit Function
EH:
    ' Application.PathSeparator property does not exist in Access,
    ' so get it the slightly less easy way.
    #If Mac Then ' Application.PathSeparator doesn't seem to exist in Access...
        OSSlash = "/"
    #Else
        OSSlash = "\"
    #End If
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Supporting function (actually commented out, so you can skip this if you don't plan to use it).

```
Sub IsInTest()
' IsIn2 is case insensitive
    Dim StrToFind As String, arr As Variant
    arr = Array("Me", "You", "Dog", "Boo")

    StrToFind = "doG"
    Debug.Print "Is '" & CStr(StrToFind) & "' in list (expect True): " _
                , IsIn(StrToFind, "Me", "You", "Dog", "Boo")

    StrToFind = "Porcupine"
    Debug.Print "Is '" & CStr(StrToFind) & "' in list (expect False): " _
                , IsIn(StrToFind, "Me", "You", "Dog", "Boo")
End Sub
Function IsIn(ByVal StrToFind, ParamArray StringArgs() As Variant) As Boolean
' StrToFind: the string to find in the list of StringArgs()
' StringArgs: 1-dimensional array containing string values.
' Built for Strings, but actually works with other data types.
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = StringArgs
    IsIn = Not IsError(Application.Match(StrToFind, arr, False))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
Function FolderPath(FilePath As String) As String

    '--------------------------------------------------
    'Returns the folder path form the file path.

    'Written by:    Christos Samaras
    'Date:          06/11/2013
    '--------------------------------------------------

    Dim FileName As String

    With WorksheetFunction
        FileName = Mid(FilePath, .Find("*", .Substitute(FilePath, "\", "*", Len(FilePath) - _
                    Len(.Substitute(FilePath, "\", "")))) + 1, Len(FilePath))
    End With

    FolderPath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileName) - 1)

End Function
```

If you don't want to remove the last backslash "\" at the end of the folder's path, change the last line with this:

```
FolderPath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(FileName))
```

Example:

```
FolderPath("C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\LAT Analysers Signal Correction\1\TP 14_03_2013_5.csv")
```

gives:

> C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\LAT Analysers Signal Correction\1

or

> C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\LAT Analysers Signal Correction\1\

in the second case (note that there is a backslash at the end).

I hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

Use these codes and enjoy it.

```
Public Function GetDirectoryName(ByVal source As String) As String()
Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection

Dim source_file() As String
Dim i As Integer        

queue.Add fso.GetFolder(source) 'obviously replace

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    '...insert any folder processing code here...
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
    Next oSubfolder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        '...insert any file processing code here...
        'Debug.Print oFile
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve source_file(i)
        source_file(i) = oFile
    Next oFile
Loop
GetDirectoryName = source_file
End Function
```

And here you can call function:

```
Sub test()
Dim s
For Each s In GetDirectoryName("C:\New folder")
Debug.Print s
Next
End Sub
```